# Как правильно сверстать кусок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: Вот чего достиг][image]

Красную шторку вроде вставил, осталось добавить заголовок и текст справа.
Помогите пожалуйста, что прописать в html и css?
Чтобы уместить их поверх это шторки и вот так на одном уровне, как на картинке. И добавить картинку с домом, тест Home сделать иным цветом?

```css
body {
  font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 2507px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 102px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 18px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 47px;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 24px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #531604;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.titles {}

.text1 {}

.titles h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #b88f3f;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.titles h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #b88f3f;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 809px;
}

.titles p {
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.panel {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: url(../img/panel.png) no-repeat center -28px / cover;
  height: 133px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Felicita</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="heading clearfix">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Felicita" class="logo">
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Our Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>


      <div class="titles">
        <div class="text1">
          <h1>Our Menu Single Post</h1>
          <img src="img/home.png" alt="домик">
          <h3>Home</h3>
          <p> > Menu Single Post</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="text2"></div>
    </div>

  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Выложите код. Без понимания того как Вы уже имеющегося результата достигли - сложно понять и другим в какую сторону двигаться. И что уже испробовали сами.

Comment: Чего достиг показано на первом скриншоте, который загрузил. Код сейчас покажу

Comment: Загрузил........

Comment: Честно говоря, замучился писать ответ и бросил. Не захотелось разбираться с float... Поменьше бы его использовать, гадкий инструмент... Лучше c  `flex` разобраться и  использовать, он понятнее и проще. В данном случае для лого - как угодно, только не float. мучиться потом, думать, почему что куда уезжает...

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев на ваш css,кажется,что Вы не понимаете,что происходит и добавляете свойства лишь бы что-нибудь произошло.
1)Надо понимать,что блочный элемент занимает всю ширину,поэтому надо ее указать,отсюда Ваши отрицательные отступы.
2)По умолчанию браузеры добавляют отступы для блочных элементов,поэтому желательно их обнулить.
3)Расположить элементы в нужном порядке,используя float:left и float:right.Блок с float:left не может быть правее, чем блок с float:right.
4)img это строчный элемент и вообще правильнее будет декоративный элемент сделать через псевдоэлемент.
5)Чтобы избавиться от выпадания из родителя,добавьте блоку распорку,это класс .clearfix. 6)В CSS3 для псевдоэлементов синтаксис element::after { свойства }
7)Удалите высоту из body...

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки по мне лучше вообще избавиться от float, здесь нет большого смысла мучиться и его использовать. Также, если планируется жестко задавать ширину контента (у Вас это будет, видимо, 913 пикселей), может стоит просто позиционировать блоки абсолютно и не мучиться.

Вот один из способов (не лучший код возможно), чтобы сделать Вашу меню и логотип без float. А в нижнем блоке возможный пример абсолютного позиционирования. Посмотрите, может, какой-то из предложенных вариантов будет проще.

```css
body {
  font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px; // для примера, поменять на 100%;
  border: none;
}

div.header-white-line {
  width: 613px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
}

a.header-logo {
  width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 120%;
}


div.header-menu {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}
div.header-menu a {
  color: #531604;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
div.header-menu a:hover {background-color: black; color: #fff;}

div.header-image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  background-image: url('http://www.playcast.ru/uploads/2015/10/28/15638925.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 52px;
}
div.header-image-container-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 613px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 26px;
}
div.breads {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div.breads span {color: #ff6000;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Felicita</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header-white-line">
    <a href="#" class="header-logo">
      КАРТИНКА_ЛОГО
    </a>
    <div class="header-menu">
      <a href="#">menu1</a>
      <a href="#">menu2</a>
      <a href="#">menu3</a>
      <a href="#">menu4</a>
      <a href="#">menu5</a>
      <a href="#">menu6</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="header-image-container">
    <div class="header-image-container-text">
      <h1>Our Menu Sinigle Post</h1>
      <div class="breads">
        <span>Home > </span>Menu Sinigle Post</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```